# Difference between "zu sich selbst finden" and "sich selbst finden"?

Tags: preposition, expression, reflexive

As stated in the question, both "zu sich selbst finden" and "sich selbst finden" means **"to find oneself**", so my questions:

1. Are they really interchangeable? Like in the following sentence:

> - Zu sich selbst zu finden ist keine Sache, die Sie von Heute auf Morgen erledigen.
> - Sich selbst zu finden ist keine Sache, die Sie von Heute auf Morgen erledigen.

2. According to [PONS](https://en.pons.com/translate/german-english/zu+sich+selbst+finden) it seems like both "zu" & "selbst" in "zu sich selbst finden" are optional, and I'm puzzled how a preposition "zu" can be omitted without changing the meaning, so are there other instances where this can be encountered too?
3. I think the verb in "zu sich selbst finden" is intransitive, while in "sich selbst finden" is transitive, is that correct?

Comment: 1) Ich denke ja (Hinweis: "heute" und "morgen" sind hier Adverbien, werden also kleingeschrieben)  2) "zu sich selbst finden" und "sich finden" sind verschiedene Dinge: "sich finden" [bedeutet](https://www.dwds.de/wb/finden#d-1-6) "sich sammeln, zur Besinnung kommen"   3) "zu sich selbst finden" ist intransitiv, "sich selbst finden" ist reflexiv und somit auch intransitiv

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference is that the "zu" implies a kind of journey or directionality.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but perhaps a clarification. The phrase "to find oneself" is an idiom in English; it has several meanings but the one in the example sentence is (per [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/find_oneself)): "To learn, or attempt to learn, what kind of person one is and what one wants in life." This meaning has a counterpart in German, but it doesn't seem to be used very often, and I couldn't find it in the dictionaries I normally use. My point is that you have to be very careful when using automatic translators in this situation. You're starting with an idiom, which a translator can easily interpret literally, and on top of that the idiom has multiple meanings (Wiktionary lists 5), so you really need a human to discern which of the possible interpretations is correct and produce a German sentence with approximately the same meaning.

In any case, I think you can phrase the German a bit more succinctly, for example: "*Sich selbst zu finden, geht nicht von heute auf morgen.*" Also, you're using *Sie* to translate "you", but in this case the "you" is referring to people in general, so *man* is a better translation in German.

That said, I'm not sure that the real issue has anything to do with the idiom itself. You could put any task as the first phrase: "*Rom aufzubauen, geht nicht von heute auf morgen.*"

Comment: in "sich selbst zu finden, geht ..." and "Rom aufzubauen, geht ..." the comma is wrong and should be ommitted.